# Android - How to get Real time (While recording) video recording data from camera in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, video-recording, bytestream

I wanted to transfer live video (android device camera) to destination (may be another android device / video supported device).

So how do I get the camera video data (may be byte[]) so that I can send the data to receiver.

for e.g., Real Time means like video call over smartphone with android video supported apps.

Comment: Below repo gives the byte array data for preview
https://github.com/bytestar/android-h264-stream-demo